# How to close iframe in parent on successful login?

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, fancybox, parent

I'm trying to make login form open in iframe. If the login is successful when the user clicks submit button, I want iframe to close and redirect browser to index.php.
The problem is that I don't know how to close iframe from that point.

Here's the code relevant to iframe that I have:

login.tmpl (html file, where the form is)

```
<div class="form_item submit_button">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</div>
```

login.php (where i redirect to index. this is where i think i need some extra code to close iframe)

```
  if (!$error) {
        throw new RedirectBrowserException('index.php');
  }
```

gallery.tmpl (where iframe is called. should not be important i think)

```
<a class="fancybox iframe fancybox.iframe" href="login.php">Iframe Login</a>
```

Edit. Here's my jQuery code (gallery.tmpl):

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            padding : 0,
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',
            helpers : {
                title : {
                  type: 'over'
                },
                thumbs : {
                  width : 50,
                  height : 50
                }
            }
          });
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("a.iframe").fancybox({
            autoDimensions : false,
            autoSize : false,
            padding : 0,
            width : 395,
            height : 195,
            type : 'iframe'
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rather redirect to *index.php* from the page that opened fancybox (*gallery.tmpl*). Just add a callback in your fancybox custom script :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   afterClose : function(){
      // redirects to another file after closing
      window.location.href = "index.php";
   }
});
```

Then, inside *loging.php* you could do this to close fancybox on success:

```
<?php if (!$error) { ?>
  <script>parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();</script>
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: thanks. the second part works to close fancybox, but the first part ruins my iframe and opens login page in main window. i can't find any info on this afterClose thing... also i tried redirecting in login.php after i close iframe, in which case it redirects iframe to index first and then closes it.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem. In the end, this made it work:

```
  if (!$error) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$.fancybox.close();  //can use jQuery instead of $
    window.parent.location ='index.php';    
    </script> <?php
  }
```

So, redirecting the parent is what I was missing until I figured it out just now. I tried using some kind of delay at first, which didn't work.